# Trying to scrape websites using puppeteer and getting back empty objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, async-await, puppeteer

I began learning puppeteer today and I ran into a problem. I was trying to create a covid tracker and I wanted to scrape from worldometers. But when I try to get back information it returns an array with empty objects. The number of objects matches to the number of tags with the same class but it doesn't show any information. here is my code

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer")
async function getCovidCases(){
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        defaultViewport: null,
        headless: false,
        slowMo: 250
    })
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    const url = "https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#countries"
    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'})
    await page.waitForSelector(".navbar-nav", {visible: true})
    const results = await page.$$eval(".navbar-nav", rows => {
        return rows
    })
    await console.log(results)
}
getCovidCases()
```

**Does Anyone Know What To Do?**

Comment: What data from that page are you interested in?

Comment: Any. For the example above I used the navbar-nav. But I am just wondering what I have to do to get any information on a page.

Comment: If you ask for `any` data, I provided a working example that retrieves the navigation names. I can help you with retrieving other data, but not if you are not specific.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the selector I assume you are in this step interested in the navbar items.

```
    const results = await page.$$eval(".navbar-nav", navBars => {
      return navBars.map(navBar => {
        const anchors = Array.from(navBar.getElementsByTagName('a'));
        return anchors.map(anchor => anchor.innerText);
      });
    })
```

This yields `[ [ 'Coronavirus', 'Population' ] ]` and might be useful for you.

Use `$eval` if you expect only one element and `$$eval` if you expect multiple elements. In the callback you have a reference to that dom element, but you cannot return it directly. If you `console.log` anything it won't show up in the nodejs terminal, but in the browsers terminal. What you return there will be send back to nodejs and it needs to be serializable (I think). What you get back from `navBar` will be converted to an empty object and is not what you want. That's why I map over it and convert it to a string (`innerText`).

If you want scrape other data, you should use another selector (`.nav-bar`).

Comment: I understand this works but what exactly did you do and what do I have to do to get another part of the page? Sorry for the questions I am just new and a bit confused

Comment: @TamirPolyakov I extended my answer with more details how it works and what you need to change to get another part of the page.

Comment: @TamirPolyakov Did this answer your question?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write back. Yes it helped a lot, thanks.